# How to apply custom font style/ family to alert dialogs in entire app through styles

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-theme

I want to change the font face of alert dialog in entire app. How to achieve it through XML(styles). Please help me with some solution .Thank You

Comment: Please post your XML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Calligraphy in *build.gradle*, Please refer [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) for more detail.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
}
```

Use below code in your Application file:

```
CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/roboto_bold.ttf")
            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
            .build()
```

Create single instance of dialog using below code or where ever you are creating new dialog.

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AlertProgressDialogCustom))
```

Put below style in *style.xml*

```
<style name="DialogTextButton" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium">
    <item name="fontPath">fonts/open_sans.ttf</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertProgressDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textAppearanceMedium">@style/DialogTextButton</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextAppearance">@style/DialogTextButton</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextAppearance">@style/DialogTextButton</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/btn_picker_color</item>
    <item name="android:progressTint">@color/btn_picker_color</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/DialogTextButton</item>
</style>
```

Let me know if you are still facing issue.

Comment: attribute font path is not found

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below method,

```
 public void createDialog()
    {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);            
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_dialog);

            final FontChangeCrawler fontChanger = new FontChangeCrawler(context.getAssets(), Constant.arialRoundedFont);
            fontChanger.replaceFonts((ViewGroup) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.content));

            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
    }
```

->apply this method for all your dialogs by creating this method in your Util class and use it globally.
this will work for you.